# System.out.println Not Printing in Custom Class's Method

Tags: java, class, methods, printing

I've created two .java files, one named `Ques.java` and the other named `TBRPGgame.java`. Here are the contents of `Ques.java` and `TBRPGgame.java`, respectively:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ques
{
  Scanner numin = new Scanner(System.in);

  String quesText = "";
  String quesAtr1 = "";
  String quesAtr2 = "";
  String quesAtr3 = "";
  String quesAtr4 = "";
  boolean done = false;

  Ques(String qText, String qAtr1, String qAtr2, String qAtr3, String qAtr4)
  {
    quesText = qText;
    quesAtr1 = qAtr1;
    quesAtr2 = qAtr2;
    quesAtr3 = qAtr3;
    quesAtr4 = qAtr4;
  }

  String ask()
  {
    System.out.println(quesText);

    if (numin.nextInt() == 1)
    {
      System.out.println(quesAtr1); return quesAtr1;
    } else if (numin.nextInt() == 2)
    {
      System.out.println(quesAtr2); return quesAtr2;
    } else if (numin.nextInt() == 3)
    {
      System.out.println(quesAtr3); return quesAtr3;
    } else if (numin.nextInt() == 4)
    {
      System.out.println(quesAtr4); return quesAtr4;
    } else
    {
      System.out.println("That is not a valid input. Possible inputs are: 1, 2, 3, 4."); System.out.println(""); return "";
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TBRPGgame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Ques question1 = new Ques("\n\nOne day, while you were travelling, you visited a city. However, you had only enough time to visit one building before you had to leave the city.\n\nWhich building did you visit?\n1.) I visited the library.\n2.) I visited the tavern.\n3.) I visited the blacksmith.\n4.) I visited the temple.", "kno", "rhe", "str", "fai");
    question1.ask();
  }
}
```

However, when the `Ques` object's `ask` method is executed, the `System.out.println` code included in the 5 possible results (the input being 1, 2, 3, 4, or something else) doesn't seem to be printing.

Comment: You do know that *every* time you call `nextInt()`, a new value must be entered by the user, right?

Comment: Questext must be declared as public static to declare it properly.

Comment: @Andreas Ah.. I wasn't aware. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your ask() method.

```
String ask()
{
    System.out.println(quesText);

    int input = numin.nextInt();

    if (input == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(quesAtr1); return quesAtr1;
    } else if (input == 2)
    {
        System.out.println(quesAtr2); return quesAtr2;
    } else if (input == 3)
    {
        System.out.println(quesAtr3); return quesAtr3;
    } else if (input == 4)
    {
        System.out.println(quesAtr4); return quesAtr4;
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid input. Possible inputs are: 1, 2, 3, 4."); System.out.println(""); return "";
    }
}
```

The problem with your code was that you included the numin.nextInt() in every condition check. The above code will resolve your issue.